# How do I bind a property of custom class List to Spinner in Android?

Tags: android, list, spinner, android-spinner

I'm retrieving a list of custom objects from mobile service client hosted in `Azure Cloud`, now I want to *bind* one of the *property* of this class to the `Spinner` control in `Android` client.

As my code below, I have a `List<Departement>` coming from Azure mobile services, and I want to bind **DepartmentName** to this `Spinner` in Android client.

```
public class Department
{
    public int ID;
    public String DepartmentName;
}
```

Any suggestion is highly appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can either:

1. *Override* `toString()` method in your custom object to return the good value based on your custom 
   *property*

   ```
   public class Department
   {
       public int ID;
       public String DepartmentName;

       @Override
       public String toString() {
          return DepartmentName;
       } 
   }
   ```

   And then in your view

   ```
   public void populateSpinner(Context context, List<Department> departments, Spinner spinner)
   {
       ArrayAdapter<Department> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Department>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, departments);
       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
   ```
2. Create a temporary `List<String>` for your *spinner adapter*

   ```
   public void populateSpinner(Context context, List<Department> departments, Spinner spinner)
   {
       List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
       for(Department dep : departments) {
           list.add(dep.DepartmentName);
       }

       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
       adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
       spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
   ```
3. Last but not least, use your own adapter based on `BaseAdapter` instead of using the generic `ArrayAdapter`, that will own the list of custom objects and provide your spinner with the view.